make: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/12/include/c++/iostream', needed by 'bitmap.o'. Stop
I'm trying to use G++ (cygwin) with a makefile to compile my project.
I get the following error in this context:
wilso@LAPTOP-xxx /cygdrive/c/Users/wilso/cs_os_project_11_hw/cs_os_project_11_hw/code/build.cygwin
$ make
make: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/12/include/c++/iostream', needed by 'bitmap.o'.  Stop.

I have made sure that
gcc-core
gcc-g++
libgcc
libstdc++

are properly installed and checked the content about bitmap.o, which is the first mentioned in Makefile.dep:
bitmap.o: ../lib/bitmap.cc ../lib/copyright.h ../lib/debug.h \
 ../lib/utility.h ../lib/sysdep.h \
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/12/include/c++/iostream \

After, I have checked the file using ls /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/12/include/c++/iostream, and the file exists.
How can I solve this problem?

Is this bitmap.o your own file, or part of a third-party library or application? If it is your own file, how do you generate the dependencies (the Makefile.dep file)?

Yes, it shoule be made after I makefile
